# Redirect fprintf output to a port

Tags: c, logging, netbeans, log4j, netbeans-7

I have worked in Java and I know basic C.

I have to debug code which was not written by me. In my Java projects, I have been using log4j with the following configuration:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, A1, socket
log4j.appender.socket=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.socket.remoteHost=localhost
log4j.appender.socket.port=4445
log4j.appender.socket.locationInfo=true
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
```

After that I use the beanmill plugin in NetBeans to read the log so as to know the origin of the log. It is possible to search the source code for the string in the log output but that takes time and I have to do it for a lot of statements. Beanmill makes it as easy as clicking on a logged line.

Now I have to work with some C code which uses a lot of `fprintf` statements.

Any idea how I can achieve what I was doing with log4j and beanmill by redirecting `fprintf` output to port 4445?

I am working in Windows XP, with MinGW and NetBeans 7.3.

Comment: Which OS are you working in? Does the solution have to be portable?

Comment: Working in windows..does not need to be portable..Edited original question

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your C code is a substitute for log4j?

Comment: I am debugging someone else's code. I just need a tool similar to what i achieve with log4j and beanmill to pinpoint where a particular line is being printed from.

Comment: What program is listening on port 4445?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the snippet you have mentioned, you are basically writing to a **socket** which is `localhost:4445`.

You don't need to redirect `fprintf` to a *port*. You need to achieve *socket communication* using `fprintf`.

But a *socket* is not a *file handle* and so you cannot use `fprintf` in this case. You can use `fprintfsock` which is specially designed for working with sockets. On Windows, you can do something like this:

```
#define fprintf(a,b,...) fprintfsock(a,b,__VA_ARGS__)

void fprintfsock( SOCKET s, const char* f, ... )
{
    va_list a;
    va_start( a, f );
    //vsnprintf will return total number of characters excluiding null-terminator
    int l = vsnprintf( 0, 0, f, a ) + 1 ;
    char* buf = (char*) malloc(l);
    va_start( a, f );
    // vsnprintf will write at most l characters including null-terminator
    vsnprintf( buf, l, f, a );
    send( s, buf, l, 0 );
    free( buf );
}
```

Comment: One should note, that doing so a valid socket descriptor different from `stdin`/`stderr` needs to be passed to `fprintf()` as the first parameter. Which implies modification of the sources in case `stdin`/`stderr` are used explicitly.

Comment: I met a small defect in this code, the last character is truncated. I need to change vsnprintf( buf, l, f, a ) into vsnprintf( buf, l+1, f, a ) to solve it.